# Trouble understanding list

Tags: python, variables

I just started learning python a few weeks ago and I am currently attempting to write a hangman game base on a python book. I have trouble understanding the following code:

```
MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN)-1
WORDS = ("book","toy","paper","school","house","computer","television")
word=random.choice(WORDS)
so_far = "-"*len(word)
wrong = 0
used = []
while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far!=word:
    print HANGMAN[wrong]
    print "\nYou've used the following letters:\n",used
    print "\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far
    guess = raw_input("\n\nEnter your guess:")
    guess = guess.lower()

if guess in word:
    print"\nYes!",guess,"is in the word!"
    new=""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            new+=guess
        else:
            new+=so_far[i]
    so_far=new
```

My problem is with the block of code beginning with `if guess in word:` and ending with `so_far=new`. What does that whole block of code mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down

```
if guess in word:
```

-> if input letter is part of the chosen word (but here the code is using `raw_input` so it is actually a string, but let's treat it as char for now.

```
print"\nYes!",guess,"is in the word!"
new=""
```

->`new` as empty string.

```
for i in range(len(word)):
```

->iterating each character in word from index zero.

```
    if guess == word[i]:
        new+=guess
```

->during the iteration, if the input letter matches the word at `i` position, appends it to the `new` string, because we want to show the player the location of the character which he/she guessed correctly.

```
    else:
        new+=so_far[i]
```

->otherwise, appends `-` to `new` string instead

```
so_far=new
```

->lastly, re-assign new string.

Essentially, the `if` statement is constructing the "correctly guessed" letter, and the `else` is constructing the hidden letters as `-`.